# Symfony mass hydration from one repository to another

Tags: symfony, doctrine, hydration

I have the next code that is executed ok but it takes too much time... is there any way i can optomize the this with createQueryBuilder and update methods?

here is the current function:

```
 private function getCsv()
    {

        $file = 'Diva_tarif.csv';
        Message::write("Retriving $file", 3);
        $file = $this->root_data . $file;

        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder(';')]);
        $counter = 0;
        $batch_size = 30;
        if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== false) {
            $header = fgets($handle);
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                $line = $serializer->decode($header . $line, 'csv');
                $repo = $this->em->getRepository(Article::class);
                if(isset($line['DOS'])){
                    $counter ++;

                    $arts = $repo->findBy(array('dos' => $line['DOS'], 'ref' => $line['REF']));

                    $used_metas = [
                        'TACOD',
                        'VENUN',
                        'DEV',
                        'PUB',
                        'ALZTXREMMAX',
                        'ALZTXREMMAXLALPHA',                    
                    ];

                    foreach($arts as $art){                        
                        foreach ($used_metas as $metakey ) {

                            $meta_obj = new ArticleMeta();
                            $meta_obj->setName($metakey);
                            $meta_obj->setValue($line[$metakey]);
                            $meta_obj->setArticle($art);
                            $this->em->persist($meta_obj);
                        }
                    }   
                    if (($counter % $batch_size) === 0) {                   
                        $this->em->flush();
                        $this->em->clear(); 
                    }

                    if(($counter % 500) == 0){                   
                        Message::write("$counter lines added", 4);
                    }
                }
            }
            Message::write("$counter lines added", 4);
            Message::write("Done", 3);
            $this->em->flush();
            $this->em->clear(); 
            fclose($handle);           
        }
    }
```

The objective is to get the Article and assign new values to the ArticleMeta.
Any idea?

Comment: I'll suggest you some improvements points

Comment: What is the average of lines into your csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `CsvEncoder` directly without the Serializer, you are using the decoding without the denormalization.

I distinguish 2 ways to improve performances

### No code change

You should index the pair `ref-dos` into your database, this will really increase query time.

But the time to execute your script will grow with the number of lines of your file.

### One big query

You could parse one time your file, extract all the `dos` and `ref`, and then build an array with pair `ref-dos`.

Example: [`ABCD-1234`, `BCDE-2345`, ... ]

After that you can do `ONE` big query to your database, and avoid the one query/line, that IMO is very time-consuming.

This way is less related to the number of lines because you're querying the database once.

This way IMO is the best one

---

Moreover you can declare `$used_metas` and `$repo` outside the while.

You're already using batching + entity manager cleanup, this is a good way while inserting many entities with Doctrine.

---

If you really want to go fast you could use raw SQL and avoid the doctrine entity hydration. But I don't recommend you this way